# handling connection problems in jquery/php chat client

Tags: php, jquery, connection, chat

For the last couple of days I've been working on a small chat client using jQuery and PHP.
Everything works perfectly fine so far. I'm saving each message into a txt file and each client updates their own chat window by reading that file every 1 second.

The problem I'm facing is I don't know how to handle connection problems. For example, what if one of the users close their browser or closes the webpage? What is the best way to handle these kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an timestamp called `last_access_time` which will contains the last time that user accessed that page, and on every page (Or in some batch operation) you can check all users that the `last_access_time` was more than 5 minutes. So now you can identify who has closed their window.
Each user should have one `last_access_time`.

Comment: I understand the concept, but isn't it mean if a client close their browser in the middle of a chat conversation, the other one needs to wait at least couple of minutes until he gets a "connection lost" message?

Comment: Yes, usually, that is how it works. But you can also implement some Ajax method to send an `keepalive` message to your server (Which updates the `last_access_time` for that client), so in the client side, you send this `keepalive` every 3 seconds, and you can can now check for `last_access_time` less than 3 seconds. Now you have reduced your timeout time.